# Import "dash" could not be resolved Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm using python on Mac with VSCode and have set up a virtual environment which is definitely being used by the program. Imports like `requests`, `pandas` etc are found no problem but `dash` cannot be found and `matplotlib` cannot be found. I installed the libraries using `pip install dash` in the terminal which installed successfully. Also `pip list` shows both libraries as present. The environment was also activated with `source venv/bin/activate`.

Things I tried.

1. uninstalling and reinstalling dash in terminal.
2. restarting vscode.
3. `pip install dash --upgrade`
4. `pip3 install dash`

Answer (score 1):

If you can run python file successfully, this should be caused by Pylance not finding the package path.

You can add the package path to `settings.json` by following codes:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["lib/python"]
```